# Insert records from multiple tables into one table using any loop statement on mysql

Tags: mysql

I have four tables [tbl1], [tbl2], [tbl3], [tbl4]. The first three tables have records of their own, from which a selected few is to be inserted into the fourth table i.e [tbl4]. I'm expected to use a stored procedure whose parameter specifies the number of records to be inserted into [tbl4]. For example:

```
CALL storedproc(4);
```

will insert 4 records into tbl4 according to the inner join statement and seeing their common id's.

But mysql keeps giving error: "Duplicate entry 'some_name' for key 'PRIMARY' ".

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE nums int(50);
    SET  nums=0;






   INSERT INTO tblstudteach  (SELECT tblstudent.id, tblstudent.Namess, tblgrades.Mark, tblgraderange.Score, tblteacher.teachername FROM tblstudent INNER JOIN tblgrades ON tblstudent.id=tblgrades.stdid
                                        INNER JOIN tblgraderange ON tblgrades.Mark BETWEEN tblgraderange.StartingGrade
                                        AND tblgraderange.EndingGrade INNER JOIN tblteacher ON tblstudent.id=tblteacher.studid)
                                        LIMIT num;
     SET nums=nums+1;

END
```

I also have no clue as how I could include a loop statement that can loop through each record and insert into [tbl4].

Comment: Your duplicate entry error for your primary key means that your trying to insert a record with the same key more than once.  If you only execute your nested select statement and look at the record set, do you see any surprises?  I suspect that the BETWEEN in your join condition is matching more than one record.  If this data being returned is proper, then you would need to rethink your primary key restraint on your [tbl4] table.

Comment: You mostly don't use (or need) loops in SQL. INSERT...SELECT is a "set operation" - i.e. it runs the INSERT statement for each of the results in the set returned by the SELECT. The effect is similar to a loop in languages such as PHP or C#, but the concept and the means of expressing your intent is a bit different

Comment: Anyway without seeing your schema, sample input data and desired output, it's quite hard to give specific advice on this. Presumably your SELECT is returning multiple rows per student (due to their grades), and maybe tbl4 expects student ID to be unique. It's not clear. You haven't really told us the actual end goal, other than "insert some records", or given us enough useful detail.